# How to make all checkboxes checked after clicking on a link?

Tags: jquery

There is such a markup:

```
<div class="field--name-field-finishing">
  <a href="" class="dummy-select-deselect-finishing-options">Select/Deselect All</a>
  
  <div class="field--name-field-finishing-option">
    <div class="form-checkboxes">
      
      <div class="js-form-type-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="option-29202" name="field_finishing[29202]" value="29202" checked="checked" class="form-checkbox">
      <label for="option-29202" class="option"><span class="views-field-field-image">
        <span class="field-content"> 
          <img loading="lazy" src="/path" typeof="Image">
        </span>
      </span>
        <span class="views-field-name"><span class="field-content">Hem Tags</span></span>
      </label>
    </div>
      
      <div class="js-form-type-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="option-29203" name="field_finishing[29203]" value="29203" checked="checked" class="form-checkbox">
        <label for="option-29203" class="option"><span class="views-field-field-image">
          <span class="field-content">
            <img loading="lazy" src="/path" typeof="Image">
          </span></span>
          <span class="views-field-name">
            <span class="field-content">Hang Tags</span>
            </span>
        </label>
      </div>
      
      <div class="js-form-type-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="option-29204" name="field_finishing[29204]" value="29204" checked="checked" class="form-checkbox">
        <label for="option-29204" class="option"><span class="views-field-field-image">
          <span class="field-content">
            <img loading="lazy" src="/path"  typeof="Image">
          </span>
          </span><span class="views-field-name">
          <span class="field-content">Folding and Bagging</span>
        </span>
        </label>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I need to click on `<a>` with the `dummy-select-deselect-finishing-options` class so that all checkboxes in `field--name-field-finishing-option` are checked, when you click again, on the contrary, they are unchecked.

How to implement it?

I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dummy-select-deselect-finishing-options").click(function() {
    var checkboxes = $(".field--name-field-finishing-option input[type='checkbox']");
    var isChecked = checkboxes.first().prop("checked");
    checkboxes.prop("checked", !isChecked);
  });
});
```

css:

```
.field--name-field-finishing-option span.fieldset-legend {
     font-size: rem(30px);
     font-weight: bold;
}
 .field--name-field-finishing-option .form-checkboxes {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     margin: rem(-10px);
}
 .field--name-field-finishing-option .form-checkboxes .form-item {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     width: 50%;
     position: relative;
     padding: rem(10px);
}
 .field--name-field-finishing-option .form-checkboxes .form-item input {
     border-radius: 50%;
     padding: unset;
     box-shadow: unset;
     border: 1px solid getColor(neutral, 5);
     width: rem(25px);
     height: rem(25px);
     position: absolute;
     top: rem(26px);
     right: rem(26px);
}
 .field--name-field-finishing-option .form-checkboxes .form-item label {
     order: -1;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     box-shadow: 0 rem(1px) rem(4px) rem(3px) #000;
     border-radius: rem(30px);
     width: 100%;
}
 .field--name-field-finishing-option .form-checkboxes .form-item label .views-field-name {
     padding-left: rem(17px);
     font-size: rem(18px);
}
 .field--name-field-finishing-option .form-checkboxes .form-item label img {
     border-radius: rem(30px) 0 0 rem(30px);
}
 .field--name-field-finishing-option .form-checkboxes .form-item input:checked + label {
     background: getColor(blue, 2);
     border: 1px solid getColor(blue, 5);
}
```

Comment: For starters: don't use `<a>` if you don't have plans to navigate. Use `<button type="button">` instead.

Comment: you have selected a wrong solution since only the first checkbox is used for the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing missing in your code is `e.preventDefault();`.  Your link is a link, clicking on it will navigate, and you need to prevent that.

```
$(".dummy-select-deselect-finishing-options").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ... rest of your code
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dummy-select-deselect-finishing-options").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('click');
        var checkboxes = $(".field--name-field-finishing-option input[type='checkbox']");
        // console.dir(checkboxes);
        var isChecked = checkboxes.first().prop("checked");
        console.log('isChecked', isChecked);
        checkboxes.prop("checked", !isChecked);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field--name-field-finishing">
    <a href="" class="dummy-select-deselect-finishing-options">Select/Deselect All</a>

    <div class="field--name-field-finishing-option">
        <div class="form-checkboxes">
            <div class="js-form-type-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="option-29202" name="field_finishing[29202]" value="29202" checked="checked" class="form-checkbox">
                <label for="option-29202" class="option">
                    <span class="views-field-field-image">
                        <span class="field-content">
                          <img loading="lazy" src="/path" typeof="Image">
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="views-field-name"><span class="field-content">Hem Tags</span></span>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="js-form-type-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="option-29203" name="field_finishing[29203]" value="29203" checked="checked" class="form-checkbox">
                <label for="option-29203" class="option">
                    <span class="views-field-field-image">
                        <span class="field-content">
                          <img loading="lazy" src="/path" typeof="Image">
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="views-field-name">
                        <span class="field-content">Hang Tags</span>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="js-form-type-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="option-29204" name="field_finishing[29204]" value="29204" checked="checked" class="form-checkbox">
                <label for="option-29204" class="option">
                    <span class="views-field-field-image">
                        <span class="field-content">
                            <img loading="lazy" src="/path" typeof="Image">
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="views-field-name">
                        <span class="field-content">Folding and Bagging</span>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If OP used the proper markup, `<button>` instead of `<a>`, there would not even be any need to `Event.preventDefault()` in the first place.

Comment: this is actually wrong since only the first checkbox is used for the logic

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev thanks for the downvote but that is exactly what OP wanted.

Comment: @Don'tPanic sorry mate, but my conclusion is either the OP described the task not clearly or you both misunderstood it. your logic is based whether the first checkbox is selected or not. that's wrong. why? try to explain me why the checking only the first checkbox is proper

Comment: My logic is copied directly from OP - as my answer tried to point out OP did not make any error, they simply missed the `.preventDefault()`.  As to whether or not using first checkbox is a good approach or not - why not? It is a true/false toggle, it has to start with some value.  Sure, a better option would be a button which switches between "toggle all on" and "toggle all off", but that's another answer, OP's next journey.

Answer (score 1):

Collect the checkboxes into an array, determine whether they are all checked and invert the value:

```js
$('.dummy-select-deselect-finishing-options').on('click', function() {

  const checks = $(this).parent().find('input[type=checkbox]');
  
  const set = new Set(checks.map((_, {checked})=>checked));
  checks.prop('checked', set.size > 1 || ![...set][0]);
  
  return false;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field--name-field-finishing">
  <a href="" class="dummy-select-deselect-finishing-options">Select/Deselect All</a>
  
  <div class="field--name-field-finishing-option">
    <div class="form-checkboxes">
      
      <div class="js-form-type-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="option-29202" name="field_finishing[29202]" value="29202" checked="checked" class="form-checkbox">
      <label for="option-29202" class="option"><span class="views-field-field-image">
        <span class="field-content"> 
          <img loading="lazy" src="/path" typeof="Image">
        </span>
      </span>
        <span class="views-field-name"><span class="field-content">Hem Tags</span></span>
      </label>
    </div>
      
      <div class="js-form-type-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="option-29203" name="field_finishing[29203]" value="29203" checked="checked" class="form-checkbox">
        <label for="option-29203" class="option"><span class="views-field-field-image">
          <span class="field-content">
            <img loading="lazy" src="/path" typeof="Image">
          </span></span>
          <span class="views-field-name">
            <span class="field-content">Hang Tags</span>
            </span>
        </label>
      </div>
      
      <div class="js-form-type-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="option-29204" name="field_finishing[29204]" value="29204" checked="checked" class="form-checkbox">
        <label for="option-29204" class="option"><span class="views-field-field-image">
          <span class="field-content">
            <img loading="lazy" src="/path"  typeof="Image">
          </span>
          </span><span class="views-field-name">
          <span class="field-content">Folding and Bagging</span>
        </span>
        </label>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```